# Zoom feature without zooming on specific child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I go about making a zoom like feature for a div, similar to http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/ , without re-sizing certain children. within that div. If you have any ideas to get me started that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try: overflow hidden to hide the scroller, edit some css to make it bigger and just 1 js function to center it:

```
<div id="a" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#0000FF;overflow:hidden">
    <div id="b" onclick="this.style.width='45px';this.style.height='45px';this.scrollIntoView()" style="width:30px;height:30px;background-color:#FF0000"></div>
    <div id="c" onclick="this.style.width='45px';this.style.height='45px';this.scrollIntoView()" style="width:30px;height:30px;background-color:#00FF00"></div>
</div>
```

here the script in action: http://jsfiddle.net/C5A6J/
here the scrollintoview reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView